# Concatenate strings by group with dplyr - problem w R skipping rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation

I have a dataframe all_text, with two columns: txt and filename. Each txt row represents a page of a PDF file, which I extracted using pdftools. I wanted to concatenate each page into one cell, so that the entire text of the file is in one long string. I did this with the following:

With some sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(filename = c("file_1","file_1","file_1","file_1","file_1", "file_1", "file_1", "file_1"),
                  txt = c("OUR AMERICAN GOVERNMENT
DEMOCRACY AND ITS AMERICAN INTERPRETATION
1. What is the purpose of the U.S. Government?
The purpose is expressed in the preamble to the Constitution:
‘‘We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide
for the common defense, promote the general Welfare, and secure
the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain
and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.’’
2. What form of government do we have in the United
States?
The United States, under its Constitution, is a federal, representative, democratic republic, an indivisible union of 50 sovereign
States. With the exception of town meetings, a form of pure democracy, we have at the local, state, and national levels a government
which is: ‘‘federal’’ because power is shared among these three levels; ‘‘democratic’’ because the people govern themselves and have
the means to control the government; and ‘‘republic’’ because the
people choose elected delegates by free and secret ballot.
3. What is the role of the citizen in our Government?
The United States today is even more of a participatory democracy than was envisioned by the Founders when they established
a government ‘‘of the people, by the people, and for the people,’’ as
President Abraham Lincoln later described it. Along with the constitutional responsibilities which accompany citizenship, such as
obeying laws and paying taxes, the citizen is afforded a wide range
of rights and opportunities to influence the making of public policy
by the Government.
At the most basic level, the right to vote gives the citizen a
chance to help select those who will ultimately be responsible for
determining public policy. Beyond casting the ballot, a citizen may
actively assist in nominating and electing preferred public officials
through volunteer activities and campaign donations. The participation of citizens in the electoral process contributes greatly to the
sense of legitimacy of the Government.
Citizen involvement in the Government need not be manifested
only during election campaigns. Legislators are accustomed to
hearing from constituents expressing opinions about issues of the
day, and procedures exist that mandate that executive agencies
allow time for public comment before proposed regulations become
final. Individuals may also join with others who hold similar views 
", 
                          "to make the most of their influence with Government on particular
issues; this is how interest groups or political action committees
are established and the lobbying process begins.
4. What contributions has our country made to the institution of government?
Some of the U.S. contributions to the institution of government
are as follows: a written constitution, an independent judiciary to
interpret the Constitution, and a division of powers between the
Federal and State Governments.
THE CONSTITUTION
5. What is the Constitution?
The Constitution is the basic and supreme law of the United
States. It prescribes the structure of the U.S. Government, provides
the legal foundation on which all its actions must rest, and enumerates and guarantees the rights due all its citizens.
The Constitution is a document prepared by a convention of delegates from 12 of the 13 States that met at Philadelphia in 1787.
The original charter, which replaced the Articles of Confederation
and which became operative in 1789, established the United States
as a federal union of States, a representative democracy within a
republic. The framers provided a Government of three independent
branches. The first is the legislature, which comprises a two-house
or bicameral Congress consisting of a Senate, whose Members are
apportioned equally among the States, and a House of Representatives, whose Members are apportioned among the States according
to population. The second, the executive branch, includes the President and Vice President and all subordinate officials of the executive departments and executive agencies. The third branch, the judiciary, consists of the Supreme Court and various subordinate
Federal courts created by public law.
The 27 amendments approved since 1791 are also an integral
part of the Constitution. These include amendments 1 through 10,
known collectively as the Bill of Rights, and amendments 11
through 27, which address a wide range of subjects. At the present
time, four amendments without ratification deadlines are pending
before the States. These deal with congressional apportionment,
child labor, titles of nobility from foreign powers, and certain
States rights (in a pre-Civil War proposal). In addition, the ratification deadlines expired on two proposed amendments, which had
been approved by Congress in the 1970s: i.e., equal rights for
women and men and voting representation for the District of Columbia in the Senate and House.
6. What were the basic principles on which the Constitution
was framed?
The framers of the Constitution debated and agreed to the following six basic principles:
1. That all States would be equal. The National Government
cannot give special privileges to one State.",
                          "2. That there should be three branches of Government—one
to make the laws, another to execute them, and a third to interpret them.
3. That the Government is a government of laws, not of men.
No one is above the law. No officer of the Government can use
authority unless and except as the Constitution or public law
permits.
4. That all men are equal before the law and that anyone,
rich or poor, can demand the protection of the law.
5. That the people can change the authority of the Government by changing (amending) the Constitution. (One such
change provided for the election of Senators by direct popular
vote instead of by State legislatures).
6. That the Constitution, and the laws of the United States
and treaties made pursuant to it, are ‘‘the supreme Law of the
Land.’’
7. What is the Bill of Rights?
The Bill of Rights is a series of constitutionally protected rights
of citizens. The first 10 amendments to the Constitution, ratified by
the required number of States on December 15, 1791, are commonly referred to as the Bill of Rights. The first eight amendments
set out or enumerate the substantive and procedural individual
rights associated with that description. The 9th and 10th amendments are general rules of interpretation of the relationships
among the people, the State governments, and the Federal Government. The ninth amendment provides that the ‘‘enumeration in the
Constitution, of certain rights, shall not be construed to deny or
disparage others retained by the people.’’ The 10th amendment
reads: ‘‘The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the
States respectively, or to the people.’’
8. What are the rights enumerated in the Bill of Rights?
Right to freedom of religion, speech, and press (Amendment
I);
Right to assemble peaceably, and to petition the Government
for a redress of grievances (Amendment I);
Right to keep and bear arms in common defense (Amendment II);
Right not to have soldiers quartered in one’s home in peacetime without the consent of the owner, nor in time of war except as prescribed by law (Amendment III);
Right to be secure against ‘‘unreasonable searches and seizures’’ (Amendment IV);
Right in general not to be held to answer criminal charges
except upon indictment by a grand jury (Amendment V);
Right not to be put twice in jeopardy for the same offense
(Amendment V);
Right not to be compelled to be a witness against oneself in
a criminal case (Amendment V);",
                          "Right not to be deprived of life, liberty, or property without
due process of law (Amendment V);
Right to just compensation for private property taken for
public use (Amendment V);
Right in criminal prosecution to a speedy and public trial by
an impartial jury, to be informed of the charges, to be confronted with witnesses, to have a compulsory process for calling witnesses in defense of the accused, and to have legal counsel (Amendment VI);
Right to a jury trial in suits at common law involving over
$20 (Amendment VII);
Right not to have excessive bail required, nor excessive fines
imposed, nor cruel and unusual punishments inflicted (Amendment VIII).
9. How may the Constitution be amended?
Amending the Constitution involves two separate processes.
First, amendments may be proposed on the initiative of Congress
(by two-thirds affirmative vote in each House) or by convention (on
application of two-thirds of the State legislatures). So far, a convention has never been called.
The second step is ratification of a proposed amendment. At the
discretion of Congress, Congress may designate ratification either
by the State legislatures or by conventions. Ratification requires
approval by three-fourths of the States. Out of the 27 amendments,
only one (the 21st, ending Prohibition) has been ratified by State
conventions.
The first 10 amendments (ratified in 1791) were practically a
part of the original instrument. The 11th amendment was ratified
in 1795, and the 12th amendment in 1804. Thereafter, no amendment was made to the Constitution for 60 years. Shortly after the
Civil War, three amendments were ratified (1865–70), followed by
another long interval before the 16th amendment became effective
in 1913. The most recent amendment, the 27th, was ratified on
May 7, 1992. At the present time, there are four amendments
pending before the States that were proposed without ratification
deadlines.
10. How long may a proposed amendment to the Constitution remain outstanding and open to ratification?
The Supreme Court has stated that ratification must be within
‘‘some reasonable time after the proposal.’’ Beginning with the 18th
amendment, it has been customary for Congress to set a definite
period for ratification. In the case of the 18th, 20th, 21st, and 22nd
amendments, the period set was 7 years, but there has been no determination as to just how long a ‘‘reasonable time’’ might extend.
In the case of the proposed equal rights amendment, the Congress extended the ratification period from 7 to approximately 10
years; but the proposed Amendment was never ratified.
The ‘‘reasonable time’’ doctrine recently arose, as well, in connection with an amendment pertaining to congressional pay, proposed
in 1789 without a ratification deadline. The 38th State, Michigan, ",
                          "ratified this amendment on May 7, 1992–203 years after its proposal. The amendment was certified by the Archivist of the United
States, since it did not carry a term limitation, as the 27th Amendment to the Constitution.
11. What is the ‘‘lame duck’’ amendment?
The ‘‘lame duck’’ amendment is the popular name for the 20th
amendment to the Constitution, ratified on February 6, 1933. It is
designed to limit the time that elected officials can serve after the
general election in November. This amendment provides, among
other things, that the terms of the President and Vice President
end at noon on January 20, the terms of Senators and Representatives end at noon on January 3, and the terms of their successors
then begin.
Prior to this amendment, the annual session of Congress began
on the first Monday in December (Article 1, Section 4). Since the
terms of new Members formerly did not begin until March 4, Members who had been defeated or did not stand for reelection in November continued to serve during the lame duck session from December until March 4. Adoption of the 20th amendment has reduced but not eliminated legislation by a Congress that does not
represent the latest choice of the people. For instance, 11 of the 33
Congresses from 1933 to 1999 (73rd through the 105th Congress)
continued to meet after the November general elections.
12. Have any amendments to the Constitution been repealed?
Only one, the 18th amendment (Prohibition), ratified in early
1919, was repealed by the 21st amendment in late 1933.
13. What is meant by the ‘‘separation of powers’’ and ‘‘checks
and balances’’ in the Federal Government?
The separation of powers and checks and balances are two fundamental principles underlying the Constitution. They work together
to prevent a tyrannous concentration of power in any one branch,
to check and restrain Government, and, ultimately, to protect the
rights and liberties of citizens.
The Constitution contains provisions in separate articles for the
three branches of Government—legislative, executive, and judicial.
There is a significant difference in the grants of authority to these
branches, each of which is also given an independent base of political power. The First Article, dealing with legislative power, vests
in Congress ‘‘All legislative Powers herein granted’’; the Second Article vests ‘‘The executive Power’’ in the President; and the Third
Article states that ‘‘The judicial Power of the United States shall
be vested in one Supreme Court, and in such inferior Courts as the
Congress may from time to time ordain and establish.’’ In addition
to this separation and independence among the three branches, the
Constitution sets up ‘‘auxiliary precautions,’’ as James Madison
called them in the Federalist Papers, that allow each branch to
check and balance the others. For instance, the President can veto
bills approved by Congress and nominates individuals to the Federal judiciary; the Supreme Court can declare a law enacted by
Congress or an action by the President unconstitutional; and Con",
                          "gress can impeach and remove the President and Federal court justices and judges.
THE LEGISLATIVE BRANCH
THE CONGRESS
14. What is Congress?
The Congress of the United States is the legislative (lawmaking)
and oversight (Government policy review) body of our National
Government, and consists of two Houses—the Senate and the
House of Representatives.
MEMBERS, OFFICES, AND STAFF
15. What qualifications are prescribed for a Member of Congress?
The Constitution (Article 1, Section 2 for the House and Section
3 for the Senate) prescribes qualifications for Members of Congress.
A Member of the House of Representatives must be at least 25
years of age when entering office, must have been a U.S. citizen for
at least seven years, and must be a resident of the State in which
the election occurred.
A Member of the U.S. Senate must be at least 30 years of age
to enter office, must have been a U.S. citizen for nine years, and
must be a resident of the State in which the election occurred.
16. What is the term of a Congress and how often must it
meet?
A Congress begins at noon, January 3 of each odd-numbered year
following a general election, unless by law a different day is designated. A Congress lasts for two years, with each year normally
constituting a separate session.
The Legislative Reorganization Act of 1970 requires Congress to
adjourn sine die not later than July 31 of each year unless there
is a declared war, or unless Congress otherwise provides. In oddnumbered years, Congress must take an August recess if it fails to
adjourn by July 31.
Neither the House nor the Senate may adjourn for more than
three days (excluding Saturdays, Sundays, and holidays) without
the concurrence of the other Chamber. It has also become a common practice for Congress to adjourn after making provision for the
House and Senate leaders to summon Congress back into session
in emergency circumstances. Similarly, the Constitution grants the
President the authority to summon the Congress for a special session if circumstances require.
17. How many Members does each State have in the Senate
and House of Representatives?
Each State, under the Constitution, is entitled to two Senators,
each serving a six-year term, and at least one Representative, serving a two-year term. Additional House seats are apportioned on the
basis of State population. (See State Population and House Apportionment table in Appendix.)
VerDate jul 14 2003 14:35 Feb 25, 2004 Jkt 087102 PO 00000 Frm 00012 Fmt 6633 Sfmt 6602",
                          "18. What is the size of the House of Representatives and how
is it determined?
The membership of the House of Representatives is fixed in law
at 435 Members representing the 50 States. In addition to the 435
Representatives, there is one Delegate for each of the following: the
District of Columbia, the Virgin Islands, Guam, and American
Samoa (each elected for a two-year term); as well as a Resident
Commissioner from Puerto Rico (elected for a four-year term). The
Delegates and the Resident Commissioner can sponsor legislation
and vote in committees, but not in the House Chamber.
The Constitution entitles each State to at least one Representative. Beyond this minimum, Representatives are apportioned
among the States according to population. Population figures used
for apportionment are determined on the basis of each 10-year census. (Following the 1990 census, the average district size was about
570,000 people). Since 1941, Congress has used the method of
‘‘equal proportions’’ to calculate actual apportionment, in order to
minimize the differences in district populations among the States.
19. Who defines the congressional districts—the Federal
Government or the States?
Congress fixes the size of the House of Representatives, and the
procedure for apportioning the number of Representatives among
the States, and the States themselves proceed from there. State
legislatures pass laws defining the physical boundaries of congressional districts, within certain constraints established by Congress
and the Supreme Court (through its reapportionment and redistricting rulings). Each State is apportioned its number of Representatives by means of the Department of Commerce’s decennial
census.
In the very early years of the Republic, most States elected their
Representatives at large. The practice of dividing a State into districts, however, was soon instituted. Congress later required that
Representatives be elected from ‘‘districts composed of a contiguous
and compact territory,’’ but this requirement is no longer in Federal law.
The redistricting process has always been provided for by State
law, but Congress can choose to exercise greater authority over redistricting. In 1967, for example, Congress by law prohibited atlarge elections of Representatives in all States entitled to more
than one Representative. Today, all States with more than one
Representative must elect their Representatives from single-Member districts.
20. What is a Member of Congress?
A Member of Congress is a person serving in the Senate or the
House of Representatives. A Member of the Senate is referred to
as Senator, and a Member of the House of Representatives, as Representative or Congressman or Congresswoman.",
                         "21. What is a Delegate or Resident Commissioner, as distinguished from a Representative?
The office of Delegate was established by ordinance from the
Continental Congress (1774–89) and confirmed by a law of Congress. From the beginning of the Republic, accordingly, the House
of Representatives has admitted Delegates from Territories or districts organized by law. Delegates and Resident Commissioners
may participate in House debate but they are not permitted to vote
on the floor. All serve on committees of the House and possess powers and privileges equal to other Members in committee, including
the right to vote in committee. Currently, there are four Delegates
in the House and one Resident Commissioner.
22. What oath of office is required for Members of Congress,
and when is it administered?
Article VI of the U.S. Constitution requires that Members of Congress, and all executive and judicial officers, shall be bound by oath
or affirmation to support the Constitution. The oath of office is as
follows: ‘‘I, AB, solemnly swear (or affirm) that I will support and
defend the Constitution of the United States against all enemies,
foreign or domestic; that I will bear true faith and allegiance to the
same; that I take this obligation freely, without any mental reservation or purpose of evasion; and that I will well and faithfully discharge the duties of the office on which I am about to enter. So help
me God.’’
Representatives take the oath of office on the first day of the new
Congress, immediately after the House has elected and sworn in its
Speaker. Those Senators elected or reelected the previous November take the oath of office as the first item of business when the
Senate convenes the following January. Representatives elected in
special elections during the course of a Congress, and Senators appointed or elected to fill a vacancy in the Senate, generally take the
oath of office on the floor of their respective Chamber when the
Clerk of the House or the Secretary of the Senate has received formal notice of the new Member’s election or appointment from State
government authorities. On rare occasions, because of illness or
other circumstances, a Member-elect has been authorized to take
the oath of office at a place other than the House or Senate Chamber. In those circumstances, the Clerk of the House or Secretary of
the Senate sees to the proper administration of the oath.
23. In the event of the death, resignation, or declination (refusal to serve) of a Member of Congress, how is the vacancy filled?
The Constitution (Article II, Section 2, Clause 4) requires that all
vacancies in the House of Representatives be filled by election. All
States require special elections to fill any House seat that becomes
vacant during the First Session of a Congress. Procedures governing vacancies occurring during the Second Session of a Congress
differ from State to State, and are largely dependent on the
amount of time intervening between the vacancy and the next general election." ))
```

And the code that brings it together:

```
all_text <- all_text %>% 
  group_by(filename) %>%
  summarise(all_pages = paste0(txt, collapse = ""))
```

It seems to work, but when I look at the summarised cell, some of the rows (file pages) arent being brought in.

Is there some sort of limit to R cell sizes that might be affecting this? When I try to remove all the breaks from the strings to make them smaller, and then concatenate, it's still only bringing certain rows.

TIA!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exampel with `dput` and expected output

Comment: Thanks @akrun, added some sample data. The expected output would just be all the rows concatenated into a single row

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. I counted the characters using `nchar()` for the `dat` (which returns 21781 = 2451 + 2730 + 2503 + 2797 + 3058 + 2503 + 2722 + 3017) and after grouping and summarising with your code, which also returned 21781.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Its good to know that it's not the code that's causing the problem